# For a tree T, the tree of increasing sequences of elements of T does not embed in T

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory, trees

For a tree T, let σT be the set of all increasing sequences in T of elements of T, ordered by initial segment (s<t of s is an initial segment of t). Why isn't σT embeddable in T ? In the sense there is no f from σT to T such that s<t --> f(s)<f(t) ?

I saw in a paper of Todorcevic that it is because such an embedding implies a one-to-one function between T and Ord, but I don't see where is the contradiction..

Comment: Is the tree finite?

Comment: no it is a random tree (partial order such that each set of predecessors of an element is well-ordered)

Comment: Are increasing sequences in $\sigma T$ required to be finite?

Comment: No they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is an increasing map $i:\sigma T\to T$. Now inductively define

$$X_\xi =\langle a_\eta\mid \eta<\xi\rangle, \quad a_\xi=i(X_\xi).$$

Then $\langle a_\xi\mid \xi\in\mathrm{Ord}\rangle$ is a strictly increasing sequence over $T$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand where is the contradiction .. To provide a contradiction we need to find two sequences s and t such that s is an initial segment of t and i(s) is larger than i(t) in the tree T... don't we ?

Comment: @Cantor'sturtle Don't you think $X_\xi$ is an initial segment of $X_\eta$ for $\xi<\eta$?

Comment: @Cantor'sturtle I constructed an $\mathrm{Ord}$-length increasing sequence over $T$, which does not exist unless $T$ is a proper class. What you argued in your comment is just finding two sequences. Could you elaborate on what do you bear in your mind?

Comment: Ok thank you I wasn't sure about the impossibility of Ord-length increasing sequences !